# cluster multivariate repeated measures

Tags: clustering, repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset with 600 observations of 150 fields. Some fields were measured five times while others only two. Measures (continuous) were taken for 40 variables. My job is it to identify fields that are similar. Therefore I was thinking of cluster analysis. However, how to account for the repeated measures design. Fields were sampled multiple times to rate them under different farming practices. However, the observations are linked because the year depends on year-1 and so on. 
For me it is important to reduce the 150 fields to like 5-10 groups which I then want to predict from management data using e.g. random forest.

I found the following link here quite helpful:
[Click Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121170/how-to-cluster-data-with-repeated-measurements)

I was using the advice in the comments by @EngrStudent to calculate means and standard deviations for all my variables. I further scaled the data by (x-mean/stdDev) to account for different measurement scales. Using the Elbow Criterion I was able to extract 5 (reasonable) groups from my data. However, I am uncertain weather this is "proper" statistics. It is planned to publish the results in a peer reviewed journal so I want to be on the safe side. 
My questions: Is it reasonable to use this approach, if yes, is there a name or publications I can cite?
If no, what would be another approach? Identification of similarity between fields or identifying groups is important.

Comment: To me it looks like you've been asking variations of this question since last spring. Assuming that you have a standard data matrix with features (fields) in the columns and observations in the rows and that you're interest is in finding similarities between fields, how then does this become a cluster analysis? Wouldn't it be a principal components or factor analysis?

Comment: You are right, I am working on this problem for a while now. I have a standard data matrix with fields in the rows and the measures in columns. However, per field I have multiple entries (2-5) which indicates that fields have been sampled repeatedly. Principal component analysis does not account for the multiple measures of the same field to my knowledge. So how do I identify fields that are somehow similar. What about calculating means and standard deviations per field and then do a clustering?

Comment: Since many (most) statistical packages are column-centric, I would consider transposing the matrix into an *nxp* array with rows as observations and columns as fields. Do you have a target or response variable? Are your fields a single scale type or a mixture? One approach could be to aggregate a range of metrics over time for each "farming practice." These metrics would capture the variability over time in the moments (mean, std dev, skewness, kurtosis) or the coeff of variation. Then run some dimension reducing method on that reduced matrix.

Comment: If the fields are mixtures, another approach could be a finite mixture model approach such as latent class models. There are some papers here on how that could work ... http://www.statisticalinnovations.com/publicationsarticles/#dfm

Comment: Thank, I think that goes in the right direction. However, I don't have a response variable. The study was initiated to observe the situation in many fields and how they change over time. Fields were chosen truly random, so no underlying response variable is given. From additional data I collected I have information of the underlying farming practice. However, my aim is to identify structures in the dataset first and then use farming practices to explain them.

Comment: So ideally I want to say that the all 250 fields form 5 (or 10) groups contain fields that show similar measurements. In a second step I want to identify the farming practices that were forming these groups. I will take a look at the link you posted

Comment: The link is only relevant if your information does not represent a single scale type.

Comment: They are single scale. So I continue calculating moments (mean,std dev) for each field? The results of this look reasonable. I just want to know whether I can justify this in a peer-reviewed journal. With this technique I discovered groups that contain fields showing the same response on my variables, so I am actually quite happy with this. But before I continue digging deeper I want to know if I can do this.

Comment: This paper by Rob Hyndman proposes this technique *Dimension Reduction for Clustering Time Series Using Global Characteristics* available here ... http://www.robjhyndman.com/papers/wang2.pdf